# OpenLayer 3 VectorTiles ol.style.Text: Uncaught TypeError: a.qg is not a function

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, vector-tiles

I'm styling an OpenLayer VectorTile (hosted on PGRestAPI served in mvt/pbf format). Line styling works perfectly but adding labels creates the error below

**Uncaught TypeError: a.qg is not a function**

The working code to define the line style is

```
var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color:'#ff9900',width:3.5})    
var line = new ol.style.Style({stroke:stroke, zIndex:4})
style = [line]
```

When I add the following lines of code, I get the mentioned error

```
var l_fill = new ol.style.Fill({color: '#000000'});
var l_stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#000000', width: 1});

var label = new ol.style.Style({
      text: new ol.style.Text({
             text: feature.get('label_field'), 
             fill: l_fill, 
             stroke: l_stroke
           })
      });

style = [line,label]
```

*EDIT This error only occurs for one of the layers I'm working with, the data in the example link below and another layer from my server work as expected. I'm just not sure what's creating the error since there are no Null values in the data and the error itself doesn't tell me much.

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html

Comment: When you do style= [line,label] you really are doing style = [[line],label] what is bad.

Comment: Use `ol-debug.js` to get a more verbose message.